# Scaling axis on Mathematica's plots

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software, mathematica

I'm trying to get the plot below only I want the ratio y:x to be 1:1 instead of 2:1. I want the ellipse to look tall and slim instead of short and fat.

Here's the code line if you want to copy and paste.

> Plot[{-2*Sqrt[1-x^2],2*Sqrt[1-x^2],2*x-2*Sqrt[2]}, {x,-2,2}, PlotStyle->{Blue, Blue, Red}]

[image: plot]

What I want as an answer is the code to generate the plot as I decribed above.

Comment: Mathematica has its own [site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you @DavidMitra I know about it, but such basic questions are off-topic there :(

Comment: @ICan'tPlotThis: If a question about Mathematica is off-topic on *Mathematica*.SE, you can bet it's off-topic here as well.

Comment: @pew the tags suggest otherwise and if that is true, the same goes for Cross Validated/Statistics and Physics SE/Physics. These SE sites are known for not accepting basic questions.

Comment: @ICan'tPlotThis: If that is true, it's a sad state indeed.

Comment: Are you asking what the equation of a circle is ("I want the ratio y:x to be 1:1 instead of 2:1")?  Asking for code is more of a programming topic than a mathematical one.

Comment: @hardmath I meant the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Aspect Ratio,

> ```
>  Plot[{-2*Sqrt[1 - x^2], 2*Sqrt[1 - x^2], 2*x - 2*Sqrt[2]}, {x, -2, 2},
>    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue, Red}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
> ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I wanted.